# Android XML resource file error

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources, runtimeexception

Hey I am building an app in android and its been going well until today. i made some changes to one of my layout xml files and it doesn't show any errors for the xml page but when my code runs the setContextView() with that layout file it crashes, the error inst very helpful ( run time exception) so i am pretty sure something is wrong with my xml but ive looked for a few hours now and cant figure it out. any help would be appreciated. thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/createdeerrecordlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/titlelayout">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titlelabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/newTrophyTitle"
            android:textSize="10pt">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainlayout" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewflipper" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollviewbasicinfo"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:id="@+id/relativebasicinfo"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/deerName"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/newTrophyName"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="50dip">
                    </EditText>
                    <Spinner android:entries="@array/newTrophyBuckScoreTypelist" 
                        android:prompt="@string/newTrophyBuckScoreType" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:id="@+id/NewTrophyBuckScoreType" 
                        android:layout_below="@+id/NewTrophyName" 
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NewTrophyName">
                    </Spinner>
                    <Spinner android:layout_below="@+id/NewTrophyName"
                        android:id="@+id/NewTrophyBuckSpecType"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:prompt="@string/newTrophyBuckSpecType"
                        android:entries="@array/newTrophyBuckSpecTypelist" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
                    </Spinner>
                    <EditText android:layout_below="@+id/NewTrophyBuckScoreType"
                        android:id="@+id/NewTrophyComment"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/newTrophyComment"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:lines="5" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
                    </EditText>
                    <DatePicker android:id="@+id/killDate" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_below="@+id/NewTrophyComment" 
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NewTrophyComment" 
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NewTrophyComment"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
                    </DatePicker>
                    <Button android:onClick="getPicURLFromGallery" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                        android:text="Upload Picture" 
                        android:id="@+id/getPicButton" 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_below="@+id/killDate" 
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/killDate" 
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/killDate">
                    </Button>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
             <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollviewmeasure1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout  
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:id="@+id/linearmeasure1"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        <TableLayout  
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/tablemeasure1"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip">
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Right Antler Points"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.EditNumber android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:hint="No. Points on Right Antler" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/R_A" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></com.stabe.mtb.EditNumber>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Left Antler Points"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.EditNumber android:inputType="numberDecimal" android:hint="No. Points on Left Antler" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/L_A"></com.stabe.mtb.EditNumber>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Tip to Tip Spread"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/B" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Greatest Spread"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/C" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Inside Spread of Main Beams"
                                android:textSize="6pt" android:lines="2">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/D" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure>
                            </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Spread Credit"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/SPREAD_CREDIT" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></com.stabe.mtb.SplitMeasure>
                            </TableRow>
                         </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>
             <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollviewmeasure2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                 <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/linearmeasure2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TableView
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                       android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
                       android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                       android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
                       android:id="@+id/tablemeasure2">
                        <TableRow>
                          <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/columnLeft"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Left"
                            android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/columnRight"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Right"
                            android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                         </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                          <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mainlabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Main Beam"
                            android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure      
                            android:id="@+id/F"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g1label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G1"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure      
                                android:id="@+id/G1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g2label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G2"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure          
                                android:id="@+id/G2"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g3label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G3"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure              
                                android:id="@+id/G3"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g4label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G4"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure                  
                                android:id="@+id/G4"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g5label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G5"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure              
                                android:id="@+id/G5"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                            <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g6label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G6"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure                  
                                android:id="@+id/G6"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/g7label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="G7"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure              
                                android:id="@+id/G7"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/h1label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="H1"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure              
                                android:id="@+id/H1"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/h2label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="H2"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure          
                                android:id="@+id/H2"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/h3label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="H3"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure              
                                android:id="@+id/H3"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>
                         </TableRow>
                         <TableRow>
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/h4label"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="H4"
                                android:textSize="6pt">
                            </TextView>
                            <com.stabe.mtb.Measure          
                                android:id="@+id/H4"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                            </com.stabe.mtb.Measure>    
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableView>        
                </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>
             <LinearLayout  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearsubmit"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SubmitDeerLabel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/submitDeerTitleText"
                    android:textSize="10pt">
                </TextView>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SubmitDeerButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:onClick="SubmitDeer"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/EmailCheckBox"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/FacebookCheckBox"
                    android:text="Facebook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <CheckBox android:id="@+id/TwitterCheckBox"
                    android:text="Twitter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>  
        </ViewFlipper>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the full runtime error anyway, might give us a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have TableView and /TableView tags.  Should this be TableLayout?  This might cause runtime error and not be caught beforehand but without seeing more code, I could not comment further.

Are there any further error messages (from logcat) that point to error?

Comment: ha, I knew it was simple. sometimes when you stare at something to long you miss the simplest thing. thank you for the quick help